# RxJS clarification needed: how to return a plain object instead of an Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I am writing an angular 2 validator function. I would like to return a **plain object** instead of an **observable**.

Here is my current implementation:

```
import {AbstractControl} from "@angular/common";
import {UserAccountService} from "../../useraccount/useraccount.service";

export function validateEmailAvailable(userAccountService: UserAccountService) {
  return (control: AbstractControl)=> { //This returned lambda should itself return a plain object
    return userAccountService.checkAvailability(control.value)
      .map(res=> {
        if (res.json() === true) {
          return null;
        }
        else {
          return {unavailable: true};
        }
      });
  };
}
```

Can someone please explain how to properly use the RxJs operators in order to return either `null` or `{unavailable: true}` from the above but not an observable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would bet that this is not possible. This is the same as asking to ask an async function to return its value synchronously. Or returning a value in the present computed from values in the future. It is inherently contradictory. Promise 'operators' will always also return a promise, if you think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toPromise()](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) to return a promise instead of an `Observable`.
For example:

```
export function validateEmailAvailable(userAccountService: UserAccountService) {
  return (control: AbstractControl)=> { //This returned lambda should itself return a plain object
    return userAccountService.checkAvailability(control.value)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res=> {
        if (res.json() === true) {
          return null;
        }
        else {
          return {unavailable: true};
        }
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi. I thought that using promises would help but I get the same error unfortunately...

Comment: @balteo You probably need to debug to see where the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning lambda why not directly return the observable containing the value?